# rails node_modules redundant files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, npm, frontend

I am new to node and thus npm or modular javascript.

When I use the browserify-rails gem, after I ran `npm intall`, I realised that there already a whole github repo files under the node_modules folder.

As I only need the source for development, is the example folder and those extra files necessary? Can I just delete those files?

When deploy, will those files be uploaded as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the test files, add it to npm ignore. 
Ex -https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/.npmignore

For deployment, i would suggest keeping the entire `node_modules` out of source control and just have a npm shrinkwrap file that's tracked. That way, you will always have the same modules installed on deployment.

More on shrinkwrap - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap